# REST API Magneto: difference between product id and item id

Tags: magento

According to documentation [REST API: Stock Items](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/inventory.html#RESTAPI-Resource-StockItems-HTTPMethod-PUT-stockitems--id)
HTTP Method: PUT /stockitems has options **product_id** and **item_id**.
I'm interested which is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the database table `cataloginventory_stock_item` it appears that `item_id` is the primary key on the table, and is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  In a standard setup, this is likely to match the product_id for the most part, however, I believe this is in place incase you have multiple stock_ids for the same product.  `stock_id` relates to the table `cataloginventory_stock`

Comment: Hey, the question was for item_id and product_id, not stock_id

Comment: Yep, and all 3 are referenced in my reply?

Comment: I still can't find an explanation on what is product_id vs item_id, other than that item_id is a primary key